# Is my partition useless?

Tags: partitioning

Installed ubuntu, and it didn't give me a choice as to where it was going to be installed.
Partitioned about half my drive before, is my partition useless now?

Comment: Please specify your partitions layout. This is usually done by `fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 0):

If the partitioning process was finished, then your data is probably hosed.  You may be able to recover some with a Forensics distro like [Helix](http://www.e-fense.com/helix3pro.php) or [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/).

Always make a backup of data before installing an OS, even if you don't plan on touching a certain partition.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
As far as i know, the partition wasn't touched at all so i might still be able to merge it back into the original?